# Scan COA Sticker

Tags: oem, scanning, windows-key, document-scanning

We are a OEM manufacture and want to prevent errors on read/write windows key.
Is there any way to scan the licence key with a hand scanner or something else (mobile camera + software) of the COA sticker.

[image: COA Sticker QR(?) Code]

Comment: You can scan anything. What you do with it is up to you ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably better tools for this, and the specifics of my answer are *kinda* out of scope for SU but you're likely to need to use OCR of some sort for this.

The QR code has the same number as below the barcode, and on a "retail" licence, or a system builder OEM is visible. You scratch off a silver coating over the number. More or less you need something that can read the *actual number* rather than any of the multiple barcodes that are on the sticker

That said, the way the serial number is written is fairly easy to machine read. I ran it through google lens on an android phone and I got the visible parts of the serial number read out fairly easily.

I don't see common free/commercial OCR software having issues with reading these keys either.

Comment: Thank you! I assumed that ... i will look at OCR for solving my problem!